# Spring loaded a bean but unable to get it by Autowire or ApplicationContextAware

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-batch

I have a bean which loads Spring Batch configuration XML in a postConstruct method:

```
    @PostConstruct
    private void starter(){            
        String[] springConfig = {
                "SpringBatch/override/application-context.xml",
                "SpringBatch/override/database.xml",
                "SpringBatch/jobs/job-dataExtraction.xml",
        };   


        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
    }
}
```

I am using a timer to check a DB entry and start a job. The timer is calling the below method in another class.

```
public static void startUnidataJob(MessageDTO<String> msgDto){

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("jobLauncher");  //Problem occurs here

            Job job = (Job) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("dataExtractionJob");


            try {
                logger.info("With in starting...........................");
                JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Job launching Exception : ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem when the application is loaded then I can see from the log that the bean jobLauncher is loaded. But when  `ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("jobLauncher")` is executed it is throwing `.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobLauncher' is defined`:

```
2019-03-11 02:03:39,594 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jobLauncher'
2019-03-11 02:03:39,594 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'jobLauncher'
2019-03-11 02:03:39,595 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'jobLauncher' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2019-03-11 02:03:39,596 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'jobRepository'
2019-03-11 02:03:39,597 [main] DEBUG o.s.a.f.JdkDynamicAopProxy - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository@61d84e08]
2019-03-11 02:03:39,604 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor#3f3ddbd9'
2019-03-11 02:03:39,605 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor#3f3ddbd9'
2019-03-11 02:03:39,605 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'jobLauncher'
2019-03-11 02:03:39,605 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'jobLauncher'
```

Here is the code of ApplicationContextProvider

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Following is present in application-context.xml which is loaded via ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

```
<bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Must set this -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

**Strangely enough the application is running fine in my Local.**
In server I have 2 same spring batch java application running.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that jobLauncher was created? Where is "jobRepository" created ?

Comment: Descibe specific problem

Comment: See my entire post. I have mentioned there @Tarun

Comment: Why aren't you just injecting the dependencies into that class but use this contraption? Generally when reverting to an `ApplicationContextProvider` based solution you are doing the wrong thing.

Comment: I have tried @Autowired but it is not able to inject JobLauncher. It remain null. @M

Comment: @Sumit where do you create bean of "jobRepository" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for `ApplicationContextProvider`. You can inject the job and jobLauncher in the class where you defined `startUnidataJob`. For example:

```
public class JobScheduler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobScheduler.class.getName());

    private Job job;

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public JobScheduler(Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.job = job;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }

    public void startUnidataJob(MessageDTO<String> msgDto) {
        try {
            logger.info("With in starting...........................");
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Job launching Exception : ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can declare this component as a bean in your application context and it will get injected the job and jobLauncher. Then you use it to start the job when appropriate.

Hope this helps.